# Latex citations not working. [?] displayed

Tags: bibliographies, citing, overleaf, jabref

I'm working in overleaf with a .bib file created using jabref. My main.tex is formated as follows:

```
\documentclass[conf]{new-aiaa}
%\documentclass[journal]{new-aiaa} for journal papers
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable,tabularx}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt} 

\begin{document}

% document stuff...

blah blah blah \citep{Holmes_2012}.

\bibliography{Stuff}

\end{document}
```

The Stuff.bib file looks like this:

```
@Book{Holmes_2012,
  title     = {Turbulence, Coherent Structures, Dynamical Systems and Symmetry: Second Edition},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press, New York},
  year      = {2012},
  author    = {Holmes, Philip and Lumley, John L. and Berkooz, Gahl and Rowley, Clarence W.},
  number    = {978-1-107-00825-0},
  keywords  = {rank5},
  owner     = {me},
  timestamp = {2018.03.23},
}

% other sources...
```

I've used this exact format for an older .tex document, and the exact same .bib file and it worked.  It doesn't work for my new file (a copy based on the old one).  I've read all manner of solutions online, and can't find one that works.  It doesn't even look like anything is different from my previous code, other than the content of the document.  I checked case sensitivity of the filename, made sure not to write the file extension when I call the bibliography, tried using `natbib` (with a `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` command) and not using `natbib`, switching to `\cite` instead of `\citep`, looked for syntax errors in the .bib file, and on and on.  No matter what, it displays the citation (and all 57 others in the document) as a [?], and says:

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation 'Holmes_2012' on page 1 undefined on input line __.   
You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography. 
Make sure that the citation (\cite{...}) has a corresponding key in 
your bibliography, and that both are spelled the same way.
```

They're definitely spelled the same way.  What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Where is your bibliographystyle? Without it how should bibtex know to format things

Comment: There are a few things that could be going wrong, likely with something that you were not able to include in your compressed example here. I'm a member of Overleaf support, if you get in touch (support[at]overleaf[dot]com) we can take a look at the project and try to identify the issue.